# ExtJs: Applying height and width through css style does not work

Tags: css, extjs, height, width

I have the following code:

```
var win = new Ext.Window({
width:200,
height:200, 
autoScroll: true,
closable: false,
border: false,
shadow: true,
draggable: false
});

win.show();
```

And I want to use css styles to set the width and height, look the follwoing code:
Code:

```
var win = new Ext.Window({   
cls: 'test-class',
autoScroll: true,
closable: false,
border: false,
shadow: true,
draggable: false
});

win.show();
```

css style class:

```
.test-class {
 height:200px; 
 width:200px;
 background:blue;
 }​
```

But the height and width are not set, instead the background yes.

Can you let me know how can I set the width and height through css style classes?
I am using ExtJs. 4.0.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you inspect the elements in Firebug/dev tools and check what sizes _are_ actually applied to the elements?

Having worked with an old version of Ext, I remember that it liked to set inline styles all over the place, and of course inline styles will override your CSS unless you use `!important`.

Comment: Here is the code example in JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7sfx9/28/    I have checked the styles applied and they are the following:  width: 200px;
height: 50px;

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ext is setting the height inline, which overrides your CSS.

You can either add `!important` to your CSS properties, which will force them to override the inline style, or explicitly set a size in the config when you create the Ext window, like in your first block of code.

Comment: Also I have seen if you use the property bodyCls instead of cls, also it works. Have you check that?

Comment: That's strange; I don't know why.  It seems that Ext is checking the size set in CSS, and overwriting it with the exact same values in the inline style of both the window and the window body.  No idea why, and no idea why it does not do this when class is set in `cls` property as well.

Comment: I guess what happens is that the Window sizes itself to wrap its contents in the absence of a configured width and height property. If there is no content, it falls back to `minWidth` and `minHeight` which is set to `50` by default.
If you set width/height on the bodyCls this affects the 'content size' and the Window will adjust accordingly. This is equivalent to a child item determining the size.
Why it doesn't respect the CSS width/height if set on the window cls? I guess this is just a non-feature or could maybe even be considered a bug?